# How can we create a graph $G'$ by subdividing the edge $e$ with a new degree two vertex $z$?

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a bipartite graph and e=uv an edge where $\text{deg}(u)<\Delta$. 
How can we create a graph G' by subdividing the edge e with a new degree two vertex z.

i.e: we delete $e$ and add a new vertex $z$ which is adjacent to $u$ and $v$.

Show that $X^E(G')=\Delta$.

$X^E(G')$ : the edge chromatic number of $G'$

Comment: The title doesn't really seem to match what the question apparently is (i.e. 'Show that $X^E(G') = \Delta$').

Answer (score 2):

I assume it is known that for the bipartite graph $G$, $X^E(G)=\Delta$.
Consider an according edge colouring. Let $\alpha$ be the colour of $uv$. Since $\operatorname{deg}(u)<\Delta$, there is at least one color $\beta$ not occuring for an edge incident with $u$.
Assign $\alpha$ to $zv$ and $\beta$ to $uz$.

---

**EDIT:** It appears, we don't need that $G$ is bipartite. It is sufficient that $G$ is a class 1 graph and $\operatorname{deg}(u)<\Delta$.

Comment: Good job supplying that implicit assumption. I was wondering whether we were supposed to bisect all edges rather than just one, but this interpretation makes more sense.

Comment: Technically, this only shows $X^E(G)\leq \Delta$.

Comment: Yes, but it is know (and essentially trivially true that) $X^E(G)\geq \Delta$ for all graphs $G$, @TaraB.

Comment: I was more or less being silly, but what is $\Delta$, actually?

Comment: @TaraB I assume $\Delta=\max\{\operatorname{deg}(v)\mid v\in V\}$.

Comment: @TaraB The maximum vertex degree of the graph. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EdgeChromaticNumber.html

Comment: Ah, OK.  I had supposed from Thomas's comment that it must be that.